# Using a custom Stream in Windows Store app

Tags: c#, encryption, windows-8, stream, microsoft-metro

I have a .NET code dealing with a custom `Stream` that I need to port to WinRT. The motivation for that is, that the app reads a file that is encrypted (the custom `Stream`). In full .NET I use

```
 var readFileStream = File.OpenRead(bookPath);
 var readDecryptedStream = new MyStream(password, readFileStream);
 //it is a zip file
 var readZipFile = new ZipFile(readDecryptedStream);
 //extract files from the zip file
```

`MyStream` inherits from `Stream` and does some encoding and decoding in the Read / Write methods, the full code is here http://dl.dropbox.com/u/73642/mystream.cs. This code works fine in .NET.

My WinRT implementation is

```
var file =await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(bookPath); //I copied the same file to Local folder
var filestream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
var readDecryptedStream = new MyStream(password, readFileStream);
ZipArchive z = new ZipArchive(readDecryptedStream , ZipArchiveMode.Read);
```

The problem with this code is that the `new ZipArchive(readDecryptedStream , ZipArchiveMode.Read);` never finishes reading the stream. When I set a breakpoint in `MyStream` read method, it gets called with offset=0 all the time (therefore it never finishes).

When I use an unencrypted file with `new ZipArchive(filestream , ZipArchiveMode.Read);` than everything works so the problem must be the `MyStream` implementation.

Any idea what is the problem? Does a custom `Stream` need a different implementation on WinRT than in full .NET?

Comment: In the WinRT implementation, you use `readFlexiStream` to build the `ZipArchive` object. Where does `readFlexiStream` come from? Maybe you should be using `readDecryptedStream` instead?

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with `offset == 0`. `offset` refers to `buffer` and not the stream. `for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)` should be `for (int i = 0; i < read; i++)` and `buffer[i]` should be `buffer[i + offset]` in all cases. I am also not sure if the ZipArchive can tolerate corrupt data (the more likely case) that your Enigma-like encryption could produce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by restarting my computer. It is very strange but sometimes all the streams, including reading files from the ApplicatonData just stop working and I have to restart the computer. It is a real pain.